# SML - How to create a list out of a postorder scan of a tree

Tags: list, tree, sml, smlnj

How to implement a function in SML which gets a tree and returns a list. The list consists of the values in the tree nodes according to postorder scan of the tree.

The tree `datatype` is:

```
datatype 'a Tree = Leaf | Branch of 'a * 'a Tree * 'a Tree;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done simply by:

```
 fun createList(Leaf) = []
=   | createList(Branch(el, left, right)) = createList(left) @ createList(right) @ [el];
```

If you have a branch first visit it's left subtree (`createList(left)`), then it's right subtree (`createList(right)`) and afterwards append the element `el`, so basically do what a postorder tree traversal does. If you want to create a list from a `Leaf` (an empty tree) the result would be an empty list.

Comment: thanks, i had problems with the syntax ... your solution helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient solution:

```
local
   fun helper Leaf result = result
     | helper (Branch (el, left, right)) result = helper left (helper right (el::result))
in
   fun createList tree = helper tree nil
end
```

This is more efficient because `@` has to completely unwind its left-hand argument to prepend it to the right-hand argument, which becomes very expensive if you are repeatedly applying it to longer and longer lists. By contrast, by using a `helper` function that prepends a subtree's postorder traversal onto a passed-in list, you can build the entire list just once.